# How to make openconnect work with docker?

Tags: docker, networking, routes, vpn, openconnect

Following up on [How make openvpn work with docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45692255/how-make-openvpn-work-with-docker),

> I have recently installed privacy vpn, and it turns out that enabled
> openvpn breaks docker.
>
> When I try to run docker-compose up i get following error. . . Disabling vpn fixes the problem (however I'd rather not disable it). Is there any way to make these two co-exist peacefully?

but the focus is openconnect instead of openvpn.

The reason I need to do that is that I'm getting the same error as
[Docker "ERROR: could not find an available, non-overlapping IPv4 address pool among the defaults to assign to the network"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43720339/docker-error-could-not-find-an-available-non-overlapping-ipv4-address-pool-am)

And the [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45694531/2125837) to that is,

> ...vpn adds routes that for following networks: 0.0.0.0/1 and 128.0.0.0/1 (these routes cover entire IP range), and docker can't find range of IP addresses to create it's own private network.
>
> You need to add a default route (to route everything through openvpn) and disable these two specific routes. `fix-routes` script does that.

Obviously the solution fixes for openvpn, but not openconnect.
Hence the question.

Apart from the above links, I've also checked

- [Unable to connect to docker on Anyconnect VPN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41739675/unable-to-connect-to-docker-on-anyconnect-vpn)
- https://blog.ramjee.uk/docker-within-a-vpn/
- https://www.lullabot.com/articles/fixing-docker-and-vpn-ip-address-conflicts

but my knowledge on the Linux/docker network side is so limited that I cannot fix it myself. Please help.

Comment: My quick and dirty way to make the VPN connection created by `openconnect` inside a docker container work for the host is to start the container as privileged and bind mount `/etc/resolv.conf`. YMMV